# 404 error on jaeger-collector in kubernetes deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, istio

I've tried istio in kubernetes by referring official site of istio. In that, I can access kiali, prometheus but I can't connect the jaeger-collector. Since I'm using EKS and VM, I've exposed them as loadbalancer. When I tried to hit jaeger in browser, it results 404 error. What can I do further?

[image: 404 error]

I tried istio demo from official website but getting the error. I expect to visualize jaeger on browser.